# How to make terminal always on top most from command line?

Tags: bash, terminal, command

I've looked around on google and really couldn't find a direct answer hoping someone here has more knowledge than me on this. A hotkey would work to :) Thank you for your time.

Comment: Make the terminal window on top by a command

Comment: I tried (ctrl+small L) and it didn't work wdym by "or use alias in bashrc like alias l="clear" or edit your "PS1" output"

Comment: ahh i get what your saying I just have a countdown timer in the terminal and I just wanted it to be on top of everything so I can know when it will hit zero.

Comment: No its in python just being outputted in the terminal. I was just wondering if I could get it in bash bc it may be easier to do.

Comment: What OS? What window manager? Windows is different from Linux with Gnome is different from Linux with Xfce, is different from Mac.

Comment: Im on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux with a suitable X window manager, you can bind this command to a hotkey:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl

Comment: For Windows, there is [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) - https://superuser.com/a/1389807/990780

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to work.
I have Ubuntu 18 (but same on laters) where I run chromium on fullscreen and want clock on top of it.
I can programmaticaly alttab to clock to bring it up, but even after I do the wmctrl, when I (programmatically) alttab back to chromium -- clock disappears. So Chromium fullscreen mode apparently trumps "always on top"

Comment: @Gnudiff yes, fullscreen generally takes precedence over "always on top".